# How to compute a needed volume of solution to adjust to a target pH

Tags: ph, water-treatment

I am a software engineer and I would like to solve a chemistry problem. I have revised the subject a bit to understand the basics :)

My goal is to maintain a constant pH of a water tank (tap water). I have measuring devices that can give me an accurate pH adjust according to the temperature. For example a pH of 6 for a 70 L tank.

I have products that can adjust this pH. A pH 2 solution and a pH 11 solution.

My first approach was a naive implementation of adjustment. I defined an optimal pH *O* and an acceptance threshold *K* which gives me an acceptable range for the measured pH (*O*+*K* and *O*-*K*). If the measured value is outside this range, I calculate the difference between the optimal and measured value. The adjustment is done progressively and I tend towards the optimal range. This is a solution that works but it does not optimize the number of adjustments to be made.

My second idea is to directly approach the volume to be distributed. That's why I turn to you. I have read some courses on how to calculate the pH of a mixture. But they always refer to a pure water solution. Moreover, I don't necessarily know the composition of the adjustment product but only its pH. I feel that I cannot simply apply the equations considering pure water and a known acid or base.

How can I approach this problem? I have to admit that some notions escape me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi David!  Welcome to Chem SE.  From a practical perspective, it's probably a lot easier to simply monitor the pH and then adjust accordingly. I assume that you will be measuring using testing strips, so the accuracy of the measurement isn't very high.  Measure the pH.  If it's too high, add some of the pH 2 solution.  Mix and then measure again.  Repeat.

Comment: Also, to other users... I don't think this question should be down-voted.  The OP is not a chemist or a student.  They have clearly thought about this a lot and are looking for help.  Let's not be snobbish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) No I use industrial sensors to make my measurements. They are then processed by an embedded system. This system then distributes the adjustment products with peristaltic pumps. Yes, I also think that the first solution is simpler. But the second one will allow me to understand more deeply the evolution of the pH by mixing various liquids.

Comment: To clarify my first solution, the error is calculated by making the difference between the optimal pH and the measured pH. This difference becomes the multiplication factor of a constant volume of the adjustment products. For example: optimal pH *O* = 6, measured pH *m* = 4.6. Error *E* = O - m.The volume *V* is a parameter chosen empirically. The volume I dispense is equal to E * V. Is there a way to calculate this volume V in order to minimize the adjustments? My chemistry notions are very basic (:D)

Comment: What is causing the pH to change in your 70L tank? Is it starting with tap water and then something else is being added to it (e.g. waste) that causes the pH to change which you are trying to counteract?

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know. This is a prototype and everything is simulated for now. I guess time, surface area of water exposed to the air, and algae must cause the pH to change.

Comment: @DavidCruchon
Can your embedded system use a PID controller that can be tuned? That's the outcome for your error = setpoint - process value concept. Calculating a single dispensing increment V requires knowing the chemistry of what's in the tank. If you have a dilute acid inflow vs. a highly basic inflow, the optimal V value will be different in those cases. I'm ignoring other effects like solids, biological organisms which would only further complicate things.

Comment: @DavidCruchon
An example of how industry does what you're asking about:
https://www.pumpsandsystems.com/sites/default/files/webinars/2020/1112/BurtProcess-pH-Systems-Design-Slides.pdf

Comment: @J. Ari This is exactly what I was missing. The implementation of a PID is probably the way to go. You allow me to widen my research now. Thanks a lot :)